# lame linux inquiry: viewing PNGs and JPGs... but FAST

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu, gimp

Anyone know some image viewers for Linux/Ubuntu
which have faster loading times than the
gimp and firefox which I can install with
apt-get, or which are already on the system.

Fed up of having to wait for these to load,
each time I need to view an image. I need
something fast and jiffy.

I'm also looking for sth I can run from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "display" command line. apt-get install imagemagick

Shachar

Answer (score 1):

Eye of Genome is very light and fast: http://projects.gnome.org/eog/

Comment: Thanks. As a matter of fact the quickest of all seems to be qiv (Quick Image Viewer), which is really, really fast: http://spiegl.de/qiv/